# Onclick Event on Text to Reveal Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, onclick

I am new to coding but I have lots of basic knowledge about HTML, CSS, Javascript, and jQuery. I want one of my images to appear when I click on text but am having trouble executing it properly.

I'm creating a restaurant site where you click the text and the image of food appears below. I made the text be `class="item"` in my css. I just want to click on it and have an image appear.

Is it possible to achieve all this with just html and css or should I use a plugin.

HTML:

```
<p><strong><span class="item">text</span></strong></p> 

<img src="images/sample.png">
```

CSS for "item":

```
.item { color: #B24005;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left
}
.item:hover { color: #00B295;
          font-size: 20px;
          text-align: left
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery, just add class `myImg` to your image with `display:none;`

```
$(".item").on("click", function(){
   $(".myImg").fadeIn("slow"); //$(".myImg").show();
});
```

## [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uqo0ary2/1/)

Pure javascript would be:

```
function showImage() {
  var image = document.querySelector(".myImg");
  image.style["display"] = "block";
}

// add event listener to text
var el = document.querySelector(".item");
el.addEventListener("click", showImage, false);
```

CSS:

```
.myImg{
   display:none;
}
```

## [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uqo0ary2/)

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="$('divID').toggle();">INSERT TEXT TO CLICK ON HERE</a>
 <div id="divID" style="display: none;"> <img src="INSERT IMAGE URL HERE" /> </div>

Comment: I found this sample code to make an image appear when you click text but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the div ids work with my code.

Comment: And how can i help you SIR?

Answer (score 0):

you could do this in just one line:

```
<p onclick="window.location.href='pathToYourImage'">text</p>
```